# touch events view and subview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view and a subview. I add the subview in the loadView method in my viewController. The first time a touch even occurs it goes to the view, and all subsequent touches go to the subview. Why is it that this happens, and how would I be able to change it so that both the view and subview see all touch events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [touchesBegan:withEvent:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:) method reference discussion

> To forward the message to the next responder, send the message to super (the superclass implementation); do not send the message directly to the next responder. For example,
>
> [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];